# Render Component html after form submitted in angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I am currently building game history search website. What I am trying to do is that if I click one of user names from history component html, searchIt() function is called. In the function, I set the input value with the clicked username and submit the form again using setValue() and calling onSubmit(). What I expect then is that in the form component, new get request will be sent to get new profile information of the selected username and send the info to history component for new game history.

This is a form component html

```
 <div id = "start">
<form id = "searchform" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div id = "searchbox">
        <input id = "search" formControlName="summonerName" (change) = "backToDefault()" autocomplete="off" placeholder=" Summoner Name..  ex)dragonsoup2" required/>  
        <button id = "submit" [disabled] = "submitted" type="submit">Search</button>
        <div id = "err1" class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf = "summonerName.invalid">Cannot be empty</div>
        <div id = "err2" class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf = "summonerName.valid"></div>
    </div>
        <app-summoner-history *ngIf = "checkObj(heroes)" [userinfo] = "heroes"></app-summoner-history> // if there is get response with no error then display history component html and send the get response to history component
</form>
```

This is .service of the form

```
 getdata(name: string): Observable<LOLUserData>{
 this.setURL(name);
 return this.http.get<LOLUserData>(this.apiurl, httpOptions).pipe(
 map(res => res),
 catchError(error => {return throwError(true);}));
 }
```

This is .ts for the form

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { LOLUserData } from './lolinterface';
import { SummonerService } from './summoner.service';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Component({
  selector: 'app-summoner',
  templateUrl: './summoner.component.html',
  providers: [ SummonerService ],
  styleUrls: ['./summoner.component.css']
})
export class SummonerComponent implements OnInit{

  private typed : boolean = false;
  private heroes: LOLUserData;
  private url: string = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/8.19.1/img/profileicon/';
  private profileimg: string = "";
  private notMatching: boolean = false;
  private errorMsg: string = "";
  public form: FormGroup;
  public summonerName: FormControl;
  private fromClick : boolean = false;
  private submitted: boolean = false;
  private wrong: boolean = false;
  constructor(private summonerService: SummonerService, private zone: NgZone) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.summonerName = new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      summonerName: this.summonerName
    });
  }

  getHeroes(name: string): void {
    this.summonerService.getdata(name)
    .subscribe(hero => 
        this.zone.run(() => {
        this.heroes = hero;
        this.heroes.profileimg = this.url + this.heroes.profileIconId + ".png";
        this.heroes.searchForm = this.form;
      }),
      (error => 
      {
        this.setErrValue(this.heroes)
        console.log(this.notMatching);
      }),
      () => console.log("done")
    )
  }
  setErrValue(ob: any){
    this.submitted = false;
    if(ob == null){
      let err2 = document.getElementById("err2");
      err2.style.display = "block";
      err2.innerHTML = "Cannot find the Summoner";
    }
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;

    if(this.form.invalid){
      let err1 = document.getElementById("err1");
      if(err1 != null || err1.style.display == "none"){
        err1.style.display = "block";
      }
      this.submitted = false;
      return;
    }
    this.getHeroes(this.form.get("summonerName").value);//sending get request
  }

  backToDefault(){
    this.heroes = null;
  }

  checkObj(hrs: LOLUserData) : boolean{
    let input = document.getElementById("search");
    let start = document.getElementById("start");
    let error1 = document.getElementById("err1");
    let error2 = document.getElementById("err2");
    let logo = document.getElementById("textLogo");
    let html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];

    if(hrs != null){
      this.submitted = false;

      this.form.get("summonerName").markAsPristine();
      this.form.get("summonerName").markAsUntouched();

      html.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 60%, #07131A), url('../../assets/Bilgewater.jpg')";
      html.style.backgroundColor = "#07131A";
      html.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
      html.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";

      input.style.marginTop = "0";

      logo.style.display = "none";

      start.style.marginTop = "0";
      start.style.paddingTop = "0";
      start.style.border = "none";
      start.style.borderRadius = "0";
      //start.style.borderBottom = "2px solid #D4D9FF";
      //start.style.boxShadow = "0 1px #9AA2E3";

      if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        start.style.height= "60px"
      }
      else{
        start.style.height= "90px"
      }

      if(error1 != null){
        error1.style.display="none";
      }
      if(error2 != null){
        error2.style.display="none";
      }

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is a part of history component ts file. @input is the value from the form component (profile information) and using that, there are another get requests in the history component.

```
    @Input('userinfo') private info: LOLUserData; 

  constructor(private summonerComponent: SummonerComponent, private summonerHistoryService: SummonerHistoryService, private summonerOneGameHistoryService: SummonerOnegameHistoryService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.info != null){
        console.log("not null = " + this.info);
        this.findHistory();
    }
  }
```

This is a part of the history component html after getting all get responses.

```
<div class = "forone">
    <div class = "accountforone" >
    <p (click) = "searchIt("username")">username</p>
</div>
```

This is the (click) function

```
searchIt(accid: string){
    this.summonerComponent.form.get("summonerName").setValue(accid);
    this.summonerComponent.onSubmit();
}
```

If I type new username and submit the form again by pressing enter or clicking a submit button, game history in history html changes well with new history of new username. If I used the technique above, I could check that new profile information was received but previous game history remained in the history component ( ngOnInit() did not even get called ). I tried to manually call ngOnInit() from searchIt function but it doesn't change anything but shows error message saying that variable for saving images are not defined.

Please rescue me from this problem.

Comment: I`m abit confused,
your sending "username" as the username? that what your trying to do?

Comment: @Talg123 sorry, that is just example. parameter for searchIt function is from get response, so it should be like <p (click) = "searchIt(get_response[1])">{{get_response[1]}}</p> where get_response[1] is one of the usernames in a game. In History component, once I got a get responses, I stored them in arrays. get_response, for example, is one of the arrays that I store one of get responses.